# XCTestcase How to mock C++ objects

Tags: xctest

I am using XCTestCase to write unit tests for my mobile devices. I have code written in C++ I would like to test. I need a way to mock some of the C++ calls. Does anyone know of a framework like OCMock that works for C++ using the XCTestCase framework? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm hitting the wall with the same issue